# C++: Header-only project, static const non-integral

Tags: c++

I have a **header-only project**. Inside it I have a class. Inside it (or anywhere else actually) I would like to have  constant data (enum values to string and vice-verse). This problem seems a lot harder that I expected.

```
typedef boost::bimap<MyEnum,std::string> Data;
```

**What I tried and did not work:**

1. `static Data const s_data = _initData();`: Error is like: *`only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class`*.
2. `static Data const * const s_pData = _initData();`: The `_initData()` function had a static local variable (which became filled on first call), and returned the address of it. Did not work with the same reason as above.

**What I tried and worked, but I consider it ugly:**

```
class Ugly {
public:
    static MyEnum lookupByName(std::string s)
    {
        MyEnum ret;
        lookup(ret,s,true);
        return ret;
    }
    static String lookupByEnum(MyEnum e)
    {
        std::string ret;
        lookup(e,ret,false);
        return ret;
    }
    static void lookup(MyEnum &e, std::string &s, bool etos)
    {
        static Data s_data = _fill();
        if(etos)
            s = /* ... */;
        else
            e = /* ... */;
    }
    static Data _fill(){ /* ... */ };
};
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simpler is

```
static T& global_t()
{ static T z = initializer; return z; }
```

`global_t()` can be used whereve a T value is required.

**NOTE**:
In answer to rioki comment, we must also specify the function as `inline` if it is at global or namespace level (to avoid the  "multiple instances" problem towards the linker).

The inline keyword is not necessary if the function is a template or is a class member-function (for which the inline definition is by default)

If the `static T` instantiation must be shared among different OS modules (read: DLLs) rioki is perfectly right, but -at that point- a header-only library makes no more sense.

---

Starting from C++17, the `inline` specifier can also be used on variables.

So, from C++17 onward, you can just write

```
inline T global_object = initializer;
```

You can also use inline for static members of function, to provide inline initialization, like

```
class Class
{
    static inline Type static_object_name = initializer;
};
```

Comment: This is the only way that works with a header only library. Note though that on Windows, you will get multiple instances, one for each module (dll/exe). The only solution is to build a dll. (Static lib won't do.)